# Do the people in The Truman Show spend their whole day inside?

Tags: the-truman-show

In *The Truman Show*, are all the actors always in the dome, or do they get snuck out at times such as when Truman is sleeping? If they do leave frequently, is the only exit

> the door Truman escapes out of at the end?

What the writers have said or what is in the special features/deleted scenes might answer this.

Comment: probably depends on your level of involvement in the show (regular cast vs extras and predicted proximity to Truman [ie - neighbors vs random workers across town]). Remember, we do see a bit of in-universe "behind the scenes" when Truman sees the elevator open accidentally and extras are standing around drinking coffee and such. Seems like most of those folks probably come and go

Comment: It seems likely that the road out of the dome (that runs near to the nuclear power station) is also an exit.

Comment: I am sure there are multiple exits to which all the show’s staff has access. The only people who wouldn’t regularly use them would be the main cast.

Answer (score 14):

The main cast regularly attend script meetings in the OmniCam Ecosphere which means that they can certainly leave *Seahaven*, albeit remaining inside the dome itself.

In the [Truman Show Behind the Scenes mockumentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frXlYeflkt4), Truman's "mother" (Alanis MontClair) claims to be effectively a prisoner of her punishing schedule. She needs to be available when Truman calls, which means she needs to stay in her house almost all of the time.

> "I'm a prisoner, and yet I have the financial means to do anything. I mean, I could buy the Ritz Hotel in Paris. Of course, I just couldn't go there"

It would seem likely that the main cast characters are required to stay inside the dome 24/7, excepting holidays. Extras only need to be available during their shifts, which would suggest that they leave while Truman is asleep and return (to "first positions") the following day.

Comment: I would add that Truman wasn’t necessarily raised with the same experiences as normal people. He shows himself to be very isolated. That is, outside of the regular cast, he may not think anything of seeing completely random people outside of his acquaintance, far more than a tiny, isolated community would ever support, simply because that is what he was raised with. Even when he begins to notice things, he thinks nothing of _where_ these unknown people are coming from, only that, say, there are suddenly a lot of cars on the road. It would be easy to swap “extras” at any time.

Comment: @Dúthomas - Well, we learn from the script that the offices (other than Truman's) only have a ground floor and that a lot of the homes are merely facades. There simply isn't sufficient living room on the island for a full community but we also learn that places where Truman doesn't often visit are "curiously devoid of people" which would suggest that they're only populating places he's likely to go